# macros and function within loop

Tags: c, macros

```
#define SUM(x,y) ((x)+(y))
void print(){
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    printf("sum=%d\n", SUM(i,i+1));
}
```

Is there any benefit in using the macro SUM like above? I read that macros are useful when there is a loop with a function call inside.

Comment: No, it's just obfuscation.

Comment: "I read" Where? Citation please.

Comment: a benefit of macros can be not having to duplicate code just to deal with different types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For very simple computation, call function may have more overhead than the actual computation itself; in a loop, the situation even worse.

However, you need to define your function replacement macro carefully to only evaluate its arguments once. For example, if you have a macro like this

```
#define DOUBLE(i) ((i) + (i))
```

and you call it like this `DOUBLE(i++)`, it will be expanded to `(i++)+(i++)`, and this will cause undefined behavior in C. That is why inline function, which will evaluate its arguments only once, is preferable than macro.

Comment: You example would also be undefined behavior if `SUM` would be a function.

Comment: Would be better to mention inline functions in the first paragraph and mention that they avoid call overhead.

Comment: @Potatoswatter My intention is to give a direct answer in the first paragraph to the question in the original post. And point out possible pitfalls, alternatives and other additional information in the following paragraph.

Comment: It's your prerogative. Personally, if an alternative is superior almost all the time due to such a serious pitfall of question topic, I'll give it top billing.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Good point. We are here not only to answer questions but also, more importantly, to share our experience. I will adopt this organization of answer when I try to answer a question next time. Thank you.